# LinearRegression by given last n rows

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn, linear-regression

I'm currently working on a time-series model. It's very simple. I'm deploying last row OHLC (open, high, low, close) value and trying to predict next close. Simple and useless. But what i want to do is to give last 10 days to predict tomorrow's price. I know it's not going to be accurate but this is what i am trying to do.

Here how i get the NextClose and apply it to Linear Regression model:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression

df = pd.read_csv("./EURUSD.csv")
days = 1
df['NextClose'] = df['Close'].shift(-days)
df = df.dropna()
total = len(df)
test_ratio = 0.30
test_size = int(total * test_ratio)

total = len(df)
test_ratio = 0.30
test_size = int(total * test_ratio)
X = df[['Open', 'High', 'Low', 'Close']]
y = df[['NextClose']]
#build test and train data
X_train = X[:-test_size]
y_train = y[:-test_size]
X_test = X[-test_size:]
y_test = y[-test_size:]
# build model
lr = LinearRegression()
lr.fit(X_train, y_train)
y_pred = lr.predict(X_test)
plt.scatter(y_pred, y_test)
plt.show()
```

In this case, i am giving only the final row. What I want to do is to feed last 10-20 rows.

Comment: I am not sure how your DataFrame looks like, but as I understand you are trying to predict next close given only last 10 days ( rows of your CSV ), right? Not sure what you mean by 'giving only the final row'. Giving the final row to test it?

Comment: I want to give last 10 rows and predict the next close. In current regression we only give 1 row not 10

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is a similar data transformation to the one described in the function **create_dataset** on this [MachineLearningMastery page](https://machinelearningmastery.com/time-series-prediction-lstm-recurrent-neural-networks-python-keras/) (see the section *LSTM for Regression Using the Window Method*).

The goal is to use the data from rows t:(t+days) to predict the closing price at row (t+days)+1.

The X_train matrix will have `days * X.shape[1]` columns in each row, which in the example below represents the flattened data from 10 days worth of data.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression

# generate random data to test
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.normal(size=(2000, 4)))
df.columns = ['Open', 'High', 'Low', 'Close']

days = 10
df = df.dropna()

total = len(df)
test_ratio = 0.30
test_size = int(total * test_ratio)
X = df[['Open', 'High', 'Low', 'Close']]
y = df['Close'].shift(-days)

# this function based on the MachineLearningMastery page mentioned 
def create_dataset(X, y, look_back=1):
    dataX, dataY = [], []
    for i in range(X.shape[0]-look_back):
        a = X.iloc[i:(i+look_back), :].values.flatten()
        dataX.append(a)
        dataY.append(y.iloc[i])

    return np.array(dataX), np.array(dataY)

#build test and train data
X_train, y_train = create_dataset(X[:-test_size], y[:-test_size], look_back=days)
X_test, y_test = create_dataset(X[-test_size:], y[-test_size:], look_back=days)
# build model
lr = LinearRegression()
lr.fit(X_train, y_train)
y_pred = lr.predict(X_test)
plt.scatter(y_pred, y_test)
plt.show()
```